# how to avoid paper skip in dot matrix printer

Tags: printer, dot-matrix-printer

How to Avoid the paper skip in dot matrix printer ,

for every print , my printer wasting around 2 pages,

How to fix this problem ,

Comment: What application are you using to print? On what OS?

Comment: What printer? how is it connected? is it supported by your application? How specifically does it "waste" the paper?

Answer (score 0):

Most printers have a hardware setting to eject the page and some will further have an eject and return to top setting. Basically advances the page for removal and then returns to the top of form.  In addition, the application may send a form feed at the start of the document.

More info, as noted in the comment, would help.  Make model of printer and connection method (LPT/COM, etc) may also assist.